# Чем можно воспользоваться, чтобы вызвать функцию из работающего кода с помощью другого кода?

Tags: python, aiogram

Допустим, у меня есть бот

```
# Initialize bot and dispatcher
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])

async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):


    await message.reply("Hi!\nI'm EchoBot!\nPowered by aiogram.")




async def send_specific_message():
    await bot.send_message("some_id", "some text")



if __name__ == '__main__':

    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Как вызвать функцию "send_specific_message" через другой код(выполнить эту функцию надо именно не создавая новый instance телеграм бота, а вызвать именно в этом коде, приведенном сверху.

Comment: Честно, не совсем понял что требуется. То есть нужно уже после начала прослушки команд что-то выполнить?